# What is the best algorithm to shuffle cards?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, shuffle

Given a finite set of N cards, 
what is the best way (algorithm) to shuffle the cards so I will have the best shuffled pack of cards with minimum steps to get maximum random permutations?

What is the best solution in minimum steps?

Comment: How do you define `"the best shuffled pack of cards"`?

Comment: Define "best". Also, this question is either primarily opinion-based, or asking for suggestions of 3rd party content, both of which are off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: minimum steps and the distances between cards, obviously some types of shuffles are superior to others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the tenuous connection between real-world card shuffling methods and programming or computer science.

Comment: See e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation

Comment: If you are looking for an efficient randomization algorithm this is one of the best: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @TalAvissar So with MORE distance between adjacent cards and minimum steps makes one shuffle combination better than other?

Answer (score 9):

Use [Fisher Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Many programming languages use variant of this algorithm to shuffle elements of finite set. This is the pseudo code of Fisher Yates algorithm (optimised version by Richard Durstenfeld):

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..N-1):
for i from N−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

This algorithm ensures uniform distribution. For `N` cards, there are **N!** shuffled combinations possible. Here any of these `N!` permutations is equally likely to be returned. Time complexity is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic (which I believe is provably the best, using the exact number of bits needed for len(x) factorial permutations):

```
def shuffle(x):
    """Shuffle list x in place, and return None."""
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Comment: Looks right. The important point is that you swap with a random number on i to N, not 0 to N as you might first think. Swapping on 0 to N gives a strange, non-uniform distribution.